# pass variables through imagemap

Tags: php, html

I have a country map with many cities. i have spotted  every city with an imagemap. I would like to display database data relevant to each city when the spot get clicked. Is there any possible way  to pass variables(id?) through the imagemap in order to display data using this variable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query part of the URL in the `href` attribute of an `area` element (I presume that you are using a so-called client-side image map, using a `map` element containing `area` elements). Example:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="100,200,5" alt="London" href=
  "/foo.php?thing=42&amp;stuff=something&amp;country=GB">
```

Comment: i am using this script to display the results

Comment: What script? And how does it relate to the question, or the answer?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   
function showMenu(menuId)  {
    
    document.getElementById('london').style.display="none";
    
        document.getElementById(menuId).style.display="block";}
            
</script>

Comment: <area shape="circle" coords="1085,639,4"  onclick="javascript:showMenu('london');"  ondblclick="document.getElementById('london').style.display='none';" style="cursor: pointer""/>

Comment: i am using this script to display the results. i want to pass the "id" through the image map in order to avoid doing the same with all the cities.

Comment: html code:                                                      <div id="london">
<?php 
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE place='london' ");
      echo "<table>";
      echo "<h2 align='center'><u>London</u> </h2>";
      echo "<tr> <th>some text</th><th>some text1</th> <th>some text2</th></tr>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
 echo '<td>' . $row['some text'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row['some text1'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row['ssome text2'] . '</td>';
echo "</tr>"; }
echo "</table>";
?>  
</div>